# Illegal option -p /bin/sh: 1: Usage:: not found

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I am using Linux and
I get source code of AT91BootStrap from the git repository

```
git clone git://github.com/linux4sam/at91bootstrap.git
```

After cloning the repository and under AT91Bootstrap root directory, I find a board/sama5d27_som1_ek folder which contains several default configuration files.

I can configure AT91Bootstrap to load from SD Card by doing:

```
$ make mrproper
$ make sama5d27_som1_eksd_uboot_defconfig
```

But when I enter `make sama5d27_som1_eksd_uboot_defconfig`   command in Linux terminal it shows me an error saying :

> Illegal option -p /bin/sh: 1: Usage:: not found

How can I solve this ?

This is the tutorial I am following : 
https://www.at91.com/linux4sam/bin/view/Linux4SAM/Sama5d27Som1EKMainPage#Get_AT91Bootstrap_Source_Code

This is the output of `mkdir --help` :

```
Usage: mkdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...
Create the DIRECTORY(ies), if they do not already exist.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -m, --mode=MODE   set file mode (as in chmod), not a=rwx - umask
  -p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
  -v, --verbose     print a message for each created directory
  -Z                   set SELinux security context of each created directory
                         to the default type
      --context[=CTX]  like -Z, or if CTX is specified then set the SELinux
                         or SMACK security context to CTX
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/mkdir>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) mkdir invocation'
```

And this is for `sh --version` :

```
sh: 0: Illegal option --
```

Comment: We need more information! `my bootloader` - what booloader? Did you write it yourself? Did you download it? Where from? What version? How acquired?

Comment: can you post the output of `mkdir --help` and `sh --version` on your linux?

Comment: I modified it again you can see

Comment: Who, `sh` acts strangely. What `sh` do you have? What linux distribution are you using? Can you try `mkdir -p /tmp/1/1` from your command line? I guess the error seems to come from `Makefile` file line `@mkdir -p config/at91bootstrap-config`, like as if `mkdir` didn't recognize `-p` option. You could try replacing the `mkdir -p` line from makefile for `exit` and check if the make generates the same error. Or create a empty makefile with `all: mkdir -p /tmp/a/b` and execute `make` and see if it works. I guess you have ubuntu with `dash`, try ex. `apt-cache policy dash`

Comment: `apt-cache policy dash` shows me : dash:
`  Installed: 0.5.8-2.10
  Candidate: 0.5.8-2.10
  Version table:
 *** 0.5.8-2.10 500
        500 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status `

Comment: and i m using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Linux kernel is fine to be built in dash. So, the problematic platform (in kernel sources) may have contained a change which is not compatible with dash. Vanilla kernel doesn't behave like this. File a bug on GitHub page.

Comment: @Gonn Can you post what happens if you run `make sama5d27_som1_eksd_uboot_defconfig V=1` ? I suspect you are missing the native GCC install